# Why are member classes initialized first in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor, initialization

I have tried the ff. code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "1"; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "2"; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "3"; }
};

struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "4"; }
    B(const B& b) : a(b.a) { std::cout << "5"; }
    B(B&& b) : a(b.a) { std::cout << "6"; }
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    B b1;
    std::cout << "END OF b1" << std::endl;
    B b2 = std::move(b1);
}
```

And the output is:

```
14END OF b1
26
```

I was just wondering why that is the behavior, how come the constructor of B is called second? I've also tried to use class instead of struct and it's the same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) is specified as

> 1) If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base
>   classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations
>   (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
>
> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as
>   they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>
> 4) Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

Then the data member `a` is always initialized (step #3) before the execution of the constructor of `B` (step #4).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I now realize I need to study a lot more because I barely understood the first 2.